# Show running count of each distinct pair (2 columns) in excel

Tags: excel, excel-2007

I have a set of  values, I need a third value (count) that places 1 at the last distinct instance of the pairing, as below:

```
A      B    Count 
apple  1      1
apple  2      1
apple  3      1
plum   1      0
plum   1      0
plum   1      1
plum   2      0
plum   2      1
plum   3      1
```

Is this possible in excel? I can't do a pivot table with this data and the "count" column will be used for another purpose. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this IF/OR:

```
=IF(OR(A2<>A3,B2<>B3),1,0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula as shown in the image and drag it down,

`=IF(COUNTIFS($A2:$A$10,A2,$B2:$B$10,B2)=1,1,0)`

[image]